# Sum over multiple values falsely returning 'Indeterminate'

Tags: evaluation, summation

I have a conditional expression which depends on three variables, say `x`, `y` and `z` (all integers). If I `Evaluate` the sum over first `x` and `z` and then sum over `y`, it gives a finite result, but if I sum over all of `x`,`y`,`z` at once it returns "Indeterminate expression 0 * ComplexInfinity encountered". How can I prevent this without having to manually call `Evaluate`? (The code below shows the problem; the term `expr` appears as an intermediate term in a function I'm trying to debug, so I cannot simply rewrite this)

```
expr = Piecewise[{{((-1)^x*Sqrt[((1 + x)!*(1 - y)!*(1 + y)!*(1 + z)!)/(1 - x)!]*Subscript[f, x, y, z])/
    (2*Sqrt[3]*x!), x + y == 1 && z == -1}, 
  {-((-1)^x*(-2*x + x*y + y^2)*Sqrt[((1 + x)!*(1 - y)!*(1 + y)!*(1 + z)!)/(1 - x)!]*
      Subscript[f, x, y, z])/(2*Sqrt[6]*(-1 + y)*(1 + x + y)*x!), z == 0 && x + y == 0}}, 0];

(* does not work *)
Sum[expr, {x,-1,1},{y,-1,1,},{z,-1,1},Assumptions->{-1 <= y <= 1, -1 <= x <= 1, -1 <= z <= 1, Element[x, Integers], Element[y, Integers], 
 Element[z, Integers]}]

(* works OK *)
Sum[Evaluate@Sum[expr, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you, please, write the relevant code here for potential solutions to be developed off of? Despite your caveat at the end of your question, there is no issue with providing `InputForm` versions of the relevant code such that others may attempt to find a solution.

Comment: What’s supposed to happen here: `expr /. {x -> -1, y-> 1, z -> 0}`?

Answer (score 1):

In your non-working code fragment

```
Sum[expr, {x,-1,1},{y,-1,1,},{z,-1,1}
```

notice the stray trailing `,` in the `y` iterator. When the typo is
fixed, the problem is the denominator of `(-1+y)` when $y=1$. As for
what you can do, there are several alternatives. One is

```
Sum[Sum[expr /. y -> yy, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}], {yy, -1, 1}]
```

The real problem arises from your denominator expression

```
(2*Sqrt[6]*(-1 + y)*(1 + x + y)*x!)
```

if $x=-1$ then the $1/x!$ is evaluated as Gamma function to zero and
if $y$ is not given a value that is fine, but then if $y=1$ the factor
of $y-1$ in the denominator gives a divide by $0$. What you have is
essentially an indeterminate form $\,0/0\,$ but Mathematica doesn't
warn you about that in this particular case. For example, `0/x` returns
$\,0\,$ if $\,x\,$ is not given a value, but if later $\,x\,$ is given
the value $0$, then that sidesteps the $\,0/0\,$ silently.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately in what I'm trying to do, I do not want to treat the 'y' variable as special at all (i.e. by putting it into a separate `Sum` as you have done here)  since the more-complicated function I am really trying to debug will often e.g. involve a sum over a larger number of variables (rather than always just x, y, z) and I don't know a priori which one will cause problems with the denominator. (1/2)

Comment: For now I have fixed the problem by defining an extra temporary variable `temp = FullSimplify[expr, Assumptions->myAssumptions]` and then doing the sum over `temp` instead of `expr`. This technically works but is far from ideal as the `FullSimplify` function is expensive to call and runs very slowly on my computer. (2/2)

Comment: @user78063 Well, it is your choice. You can make Mathematica return probably incorrect results, or else you can try to analyze what is going on in the boundary cases in your expressions in order to produce valid results.

Comment: in my case I know for sure that the function `expr` produced is always finite. If it is not possible to tell Mathematica this explicitly, however, then I will try rewriting my original function instead so that it does not produce 'expr' as an intermediate step.